# BizTalk HTTP adapter substituting the string "The system cannot find the file specified." into the URL - why?

Tags: biztalk, azure-logic-apps

I have a BizTalk send port calling an Azure Logic App using its trigger URL. The URL contains a [shared access signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-a-service-sas). This is generated by Azure. When the send port activates, it logs an error as below:

> A message sent to adapter "HTTP" on send port "Send.Distribution.DHL.AS2.HTTP" with URI "https://prod-08.ukwest.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/44cc9abed61042fd90a7ea89522ead0d/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=The system cannot find the file specified.FtriggersThe system cannot find the file specified.FmanualThe system cannot find the file specified.Frun&sv=1.0&sig=c[signature redacted]&edi-partner=DHL" is suspended. 
>        Error details: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway. 
>        MessageId:  {F2450A9B-AD6E-47A3-8DD7-5AE57A2C63DD}
>        InstanceID: {8A58DB8B-1B70-4E28-B7D4-C2A21899375D}

Bad Gateway is fair enough, because look at the URL: it contains the string `The system cannot find the file specified.` several times where it should not be. This is where the escape sequence %2F is in the original URL. It looks as though BizTalk is somehow trying to interpret this particular sequence, getting it completely wrong, and substituting whatever error message comes back into the URL and then trying to call that, understandably failing. My best guess is that it thinks it's seeing a [macro](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8823.biztalk-server-list-of-macros.aspx) and trying to expand it.

This is exactly as the message is logged in the event viewer (apart from the redacted signature); I haven't made a mistake in transcribing it.

**Why** is BizTalk doing this, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler as proxy to see what is going out to of BizTalk, may be error is misleading one. Also try using web-http adapter

Comment: The only time I've struck that error, https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/strange-error-from-biztalk-wcf-webhttp-0x80070002/ a reboot fixed it.